# how to pairing data from 1 source database query myql

Tags: php, mysql

I have data like this :
with the data divided into role id ,
role id 1 is the participant
and role id 2 is the evaluator,

Each evaluator will get the same number of participants

```
id | Name | roleid
-----------------
 1 |  a   |  1   |
-------------------
 2 |  b   |  1   |
-------------------
 3 |  c   |  1   |
-------------------
 4 |  d   |  1   |
-------------------
 5 |  e   |  2  |
-------------------
 6 |  f   |  2  |
```

how to evenly match the data based on the roleid

so I will insert this data into a table and I expect results like this :

```
   id | participant | evaluator
  -----------------------------
   1  |  1          |  5   |
  ----------------------------
   2  |  2          |  5   |
  -----------------------------
   3  |  3         |  6   |
  -----------------------------
   4  |  4         |  6   |
  -----------------------------
```

as you can see , evaluator id 5 will get participants 1 & 2 ,
while evaluator  6 will get participants 3 & 4 ,
and so on if it has 3 evaluator then it will be divided by 3.

Comment: Suggested solution: Use a loop over the evaluator table, and count the number of participants linked to this evaluator, then record the count (for me I will do a update). After that you will know which evaluator has the least number of participants, then use that evaluator when assigning a new participant record

Comment: To get an accurate response, I suggest providing the full SQL script for the creation and insertion of sample data in your source table.

Because for the moment I do not see how it would be possible to get this result from this source.

Example with participant #3 (called 'c'), how do you know that she was with evaluator #6 and not with #5?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An approach is to select participants and evaluators with `row_number`, and do `mod` calculation for each participant `row_number` against the total number of evaluators, it gives you 1,2...n-1,0,1,2...n-1,..., which you can match against the `row_number` for evaluators

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9f71cb/3

```
CREATE TABLE users (
  id INT,
  name VARCHAR(10),
  roleid INT
);

INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 1, 'a', 1 );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 2, 'b', 1 );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 3, 'c', 1 );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 4, 'd', 1 );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 5, 'e', 2 );
INSERT INTO users VALUES ( 6, 'f', 2 );

SELECT a.id participant, b.id evaluator
FROM (
  SELECT id, @RN := @RN + 1 AS RN
  FROM users
  JOIN (SELECT @RN := 0) AS r
  WHERE roleid = 1
) a
JOIN (
  SELECT id, @RN2 := @RN2 + 1 AS RN
  FROM users
  JOIN (SELECT @RN2 := 0) AS r
  WHERE roleid = 2
) b
JOIN (
  SELECT COUNT(*) AS counts
  FROM users
  WHERE roleid = 2
) c
WHERE a.RN % c.counts = b.RN - 1
```